# Parallax Scroll Site - trigger mouse scroll dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

Is it possible to trigger a mouse scroll dynamically for a certain time period / certain number of pixels?

Basically I need to build a parallax site - but the brief requests an auto scrolled intro animation that scrolls automatically to a certain point in the page - I was considering using Scrolldeck for the whole site for simplicity (http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/parallax/), my thought is that I could achieve the required result by setting up the animation with scrolldeck and then using a script to auto scroll to the required position!?  Not sure if thats possible though?

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 500}, 1000); // 500 is the amount of pixels
```

Comment: cool cheers - i'll give is a go!  does this work cross-browser then?